# How to parse JSON HTML value into Android application?

Tags: android, json

I need help in parsing JSON feed into my Android app. The problem is that my blog's feed is returning JSON feed with HTML value.

Here is feed link: https://www[.]xdablogs[.]com/feeds/posts/default?alt=json

Here is little example :

```
"content": {
"type": "html",
"$t": "<div dir=\"ltr\" style=\"text-align: left;\" trbidi=\"on\"><h2 style=\"text-align: left;\">How to view saved WiFi passwords PC or Android</h2><div class=\"separator\" style=\"clear: both; text-align: center;\"><a href=\"http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Dkqqi1-rK8s/VhYeSlpAA0I/AAAAAAAAH9A/GJps5_77rdI/s1600/how-to-view-saved-wifi-passwords-pc-or-android-logo.png\" imageanchor=\"1\" style=\"margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;\"><img alt=\"How to view saved WiFi passwords PC or Android\" border=\"0\" src=\"http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Dkqqi1-rK8s/VhYeSlpAA0I/AAAAAAAAH9A/GJps5_77rdI/s1600/how-to-view-saved-wifi-passwords-pc-or-android-logo.png\" title=\"How to view saved WiFi passwords PC or Android\" /></a></div><div><br /></div><p style=\"text-align: justify;\">Hello friends i m not going to teach you about hacking wifi. I am just giving you technique to get saved wifi <a class=\"zem_slink\" href=\"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password\" rel=\"wikipedia\" target=\"_blank\" title=\"Password\">password</a> on your friend's windows PC or on <a class=\"zem_slink\" href=\"http://code.google.com/android/\" rel=\"homepage\" target=\"_blank\" title=\"Android\">Android mobile</a>. In windows its easy to retrive saved wifi password, because we need to enter single command in command prompt and you will get saved password. But in Android mobile you need to browse some folders to get wifi password. But its not different. Its also easy. follow given steps</p><h2>For <a class=\"zem_slink\" href=\"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows\" rel=\"wikipedia\" target=\"_blank\" title=\"Microsoft Windows\">Windows PC</a> or Laptop :</h2><br /><h4>This will work on all versions of windows.</h4><ol><li>Open command prompt, shortcut to open command prompt is press windows<b> key + R</b> keys on keyboard. And type \"<a class=\"zem_slink\" href=\"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file\" rel=\"wikipedia\" target=\"_blank\" title=\"Batch file\"><b>CMD</b></a>\" and press enter. otherwise goto Start and search \"<b>CMD</b>\" or \"<b>Comand Prompt</b>\"</li></ol><div class=\"separator\" style=\"clear: both; text-align: center;\"><a href=\"http://3.bp.blogspot.com/--VqeUBa8vhU/VhYeWIiiZqI/AAAAAAAAH-A/LIuCVILin34/s1600/how-to-view-saved-wifi-passwords-pc-or-android1.png\" imageanchor=\"1\" style=\"margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;\"><img alt=\"How to view saved WiFi passwords PC or Android\" border=\"0\" height=\"165\" src=\"http://3.bp.blogspot.com/--VqeUBa8vhU/VhYeWIiiZqI/AAAAAAAAH-A/LIuCVILin34/s320/how-to-view-saved-wifi-passwords-pc-or-android1.png\" title=\"How to view saved WiFi passwords PC or Android\" width=\"320\" /></a></div><div><br /></div><ol start=\"2\"><li>After opening <a class=\"zem_slink\" href=\"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_Prompt\" rel=\"wikipedia\" target=\"_blank\" title=\"Command Prompt\"><b>Command Prompt</b></a> type the following line</li></ol><blockquote class=\"tr_bq\">netsh wlan show profile name=\"<a class=\"zem_slink\" href=\"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi\" rel=\"wikipedia\" target=\"_blank\" title=\"Wi-Fi\">WiFi</a> Name\" key=clear&nbsp;</blockquote><br />Replace \"<b><i>WiFi Name</i></b>\" with actual name of WiFi network which you want to retrieve password. <br /><h3>for example :</h3><blockquote class=\"tr_bq\">netsh wlan show profile name=\"PR.G.\" key=clear&nbsp;</blockquote><br /><!-- adsense -->Now All Information about that WiFi network will be shown in Command Prompt, just scroll down and inside security section you will find you WiFi key. Just steal it. :D <br /><br /><div class=\"separator\" style=\"clear: both; text-align: center;\"><a href=\"http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-46n32JUs728/VhYeV0OWcfI/AAAAAAAAH-E/LNFrqPhszyc/s1600/how-to-view-saved-wifi-passwords-pc-or-android2.png\" imageanchor=\"1\" style=\"margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;\"><img alt=\"How to view saved WiFi passwords PC or Android\" border=\"0\" height=\"161\" src=\"http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-46n32JUs728/VhYeV0OWcfI/AAAAAAAAH-E/LNFrqPhszyc/s320/how-to-view-saved-wifi-passwords-pc-or-android2.png\" title=\"How to view saved WiFi passwords PC or Android\" width=\"320\" /></a></div><br /><div class=\"separator\" style=\"clear: both; text-align: center;\"><a href=\"http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Q9txPUW_rrQ/VhYeWGsXH2I/AAAAAAAAH-I/KM-ijLZGP78/s1600/how-to-view-saved-wifi-passwords-pc-or-android3.png\" imageanchor=\"1\" style=\"margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;\"><img alt=\"How to view saved WiFi passwords PC or Android\" border=\"0\" height=\"161\" src=\"http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Q9txPUW_rrQ/VhYeWGsXH2I/AAAAAAAAH-I/KM-ijLZGP78/s320/how-to-view-saved-wifi-passwords-pc-or-android3.png\" title=\"How to view saved WiFi passwords PC or Android\" width=\"320\" /></a></div><br /><h2>For Android (with Root read here <a href=\"https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.xdablogs.com/2015/02/what-is-root-advantages-and.html&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0CAgQFjABahUKEwjFouvYsbLIAhWJOogKHdlHC4Y&amp;client=internal-uds-cse&amp;usg=AFQjCNENxbyS1FLFH9kyG-wx6-AP-NdtHg\" rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\">how to Root</a>):</h2><ol><li>Download <a href=\"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop\" target=\"_blank\">ES File Explorer</a> from <a class=\"zem_slink\" href=\"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Play\" rel=\"wikipedia\" target=\"_blank\" title=\"Google Play\">google Play Store</a>.</li></ol><div class=\"separator\" style=\"clear: both; text-align: center;\"><a href=\"http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-2TN0XOLoiH4/VhYeSMUySQI/AAAAAAAAH9I/BdT9K3sC988/s1600/how-to-view-saved-wifi-passwords-pc-or-android-mobile.png\" imageanchor=\"1\" style=\"margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;\"><img alt=\"How to view saved WiFi passwords PC or Android\" border=\"0\" height=\"320\" src=\"http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-2TN0XOLoiH4/VhYeSMUySQI/AAAAAAAAH9I/BdT9K3sC988/s320/how-to-view-saved-wifi-passwords-pc-or-android-mobile.png\" title=\"How to view saved WiFi passwords PC or Android\" width=\"180\" /></a></div><div><br /></div><ol start=\"2\"><li>open <b>ES File Explorer</b> and open menu by swiping <b>left to Right</b>.</li><li>go down And turn on \"<b>Root Explorer</b>\".</li></ol><div class=\"separator\" style=\"clear: both; text-align: center;\"><a href=\"http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-T0nIz2eLhP8/VhYeStEi5-I/AAAAAAAAH9U/w1hpe9PgFJI/s1600/how-to-view-saved-wifi-passwords-pc-or-android-mobile2.png\" imageanchor=\"1\" style=\"margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;\"><img alt=\"How to view saved WiFi passwords PC or Android\" border=\"0\" height=\"320\" src=\"http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-T0nIz2eLhP8/VhYeStEi5-I/AAAAAAAAH9U/w1hpe9PgFJI/s320/how-to-view-saved-wifi-passwords-pc-or-android-mobile2.png\" title=\"How to view saved WiFi passwords PC or Android\" width=\"180\" /></a></div><div><br /></div><ol start=\"4\"><li>Now go up and tap on \"<b>/ Device</b>\"</li></ol><div class=\"separator\" style=\"clear: both; text-align: center;\"><a href=\"http://2.bp.blogspot.com/--ZAzC8gqmvQ/VhYeTUbgGvI/AAAAAAAAH9c/gfg3B3XRlVE/s1600/how-to-view-saved-wifi-passwords-pc-or-android-mobile3.png\" imageanchor=\"1\" style=\"margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;\"><img alt=\"How to view saved WiFi passwords PC or Android\" border=\"0\" height=\"320\" src=\"http://2.bp.blogspot.com/--ZAzC8gqmvQ/VhYeTUbgGvI/AAAAAAAAH9c/gfg3B3XRlVE/s320/how-to-view-saved-wifi-passwords-pc-or-android-mobile3.png\" title=\"How to view saved WiFi passwords PC or Android\" width=\"180\" /></a></div><div><br /></div><ol start=\"5\"><li>Now open \"<b>Data</b>\" folder, inside \"<b>Data</b>\" folder open \"<b>Misc</b>\" and then open \"<b>WiFi</b>\" folder.</li></ol><div class=\"separator\" style=\"clear: both; text-align: center;\"><a href=\"http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-mILnm3qVtCg/VhYeTrqsjzI/AAAAAAAAH9o/9bhgC9o6PYM/s1600/how-to-view-saved-wifi-passwords-pc-or-android-mobile4.png\" imageanchor=\"1\" style=\"margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;\"><img alt=\"How to view saved WiFi passwords PC or Android\" border=\"0\" height=\"320\" src=\"http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-mILnm3qVtCg/VhYeTrqsjzI/AAAAAAAAH9o/9bhgC9o6PYM/s320/how-to-view-saved-wifi-passwords-pc-or-android-mobile4.png\" title=\"How to view saved WiFi passwords PC or Android\" width=\"180\" /></a></div><div><br /></div><ol start=\"6\"><li>here will be a file named \"<b>wpa_supplicant.conf</b>\", open that file in any <a class=\"zem_slink\" href=\"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_editor\" rel=\"wikipedia\" target=\"_blank\" title=\"Text editor\">Text Editor</a> or Text Viewer, to read contents inside that file.</li></ol><div class=\"separator\" style=\"clear: both; text-align: center;\"><a href=\"http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-A1BoqMX9Bvc/VhYeT7FgHYI/AAAAAAAAH9s/KGdWOC_TwZw/s1600/how-to-view-saved-wifi-passwords-pc-or-android-mobile5.png\" imageanchor=\"1\" style=\"margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;\"><img alt=\"How to view saved WiFi passwords PC or Android\" border=\"0\" height=\"320\" src=\"http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-A1BoqMX9Bvc/VhYeT7FgHYI/AAAAAAAAH9s/KGdWOC_TwZw/s320/how-to-view-saved-wifi-passwords-pc-or-android-mobile5.png\" title=\"How to view saved WiFi passwords PC or Android\" width=\"180\" /></a></div><div><br /></div><ol start=\"7\"><li>Inside that file you will get all saved Wifi name with Password.</li></ol><div class=\"separator\" style=\"clear: both; text-align: center;\"><a href=\"http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-mmiTp4ZRT2c/VhYeUWLF1MI/AAAAAAAAH9w/a1ioGihoIpM/s1600/how-to-view-saved-wifi-passwords-pc-or-android-mobile6.png\" imageanchor=\"1\" style=\"margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;\"><img alt=\"How to view saved WiFi passwords PC or Android\" border=\"0\" height=\"320\" src=\"http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-mmiTp4ZRT2c/VhYeUWLF1MI/AAAAAAAAH9w/a1ioGihoIpM/s320/how-to-view-saved-wifi-passwords-pc-or-android-mobile6.png\" title=\"How to view saved WiFi passwords PC or Android\" width=\"180\" /></a></div><br /><p>So on Android mobile this will work if you have rooted your mobile, otherwise \"Data\" folder will be empty.</p></div><div class=\"blogger-post-footer\"><script type='text/javascript'>\n      google_ad_client=&quot;ca-pub-7943122633795545&quot;;\n      google_ad_slot=&quot;4444892313&quot;;\n      google_ad_width=468;\n      google_ad_height=60;\n</script>\n\n<script src='http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js' type='text/javascript'></script></div>"
},
```

Is it possible to parse whole html content into Android application, or I need to convert it to text format?

If I need to convert that html feed into text feed then how can I convert? I want to write an app for my blog, which is hosted on blogger.

I found another feed which is by using summary like this

https://www[.]xdablogs[.]com/feeds/posts/summary?alt=json

but in this some content of body is fetched. Is there any other way to fetch full content of body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your object class will be look like this:

```
 class Feed {
       @SerializedName("type")
       private String mType;

       @SerializedName("$t")
       private String mContent;

       // getters
    }
```

And convert from json your json String str:

```
Feed feed = new Gson().fromJson(str, Feed.class);
```

Pass your data into webView or textView

Comment: @SerializedName - annotation. It shows to Gson library what variable name It should to use.

Comment: ohh great ..:)

but if i don't use that annotation then what will happen ???

i m new to android web services ..so that are new for me..
is there any best tutorials about web services

Comment: and there are some images link in that html code how to parse that images to show in imageview ????

Comment: now i have assigned that html feed to webview now all images are loaded

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can pass the HTML contents into Android Application.

Assign the HTML contain to a String value,
and then use the HTML class to assign it to the view.
E.g.

```
String sFetchedHTMLData = <Your HTML Data that you had fetched using JSON>;
textView.setText(HTML.fromHTML(sFetchedHTMLData));
```

Comment: then this will display according to html formatting??? 

i mean to say that if in my html code there is <b>hello</b>
then hello will be in bold ??

Answer (score 0):

If you are directly trying to display html content iin textView, then use this :

```
 textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlcode));
```

Comment: thanks for reply i m going to try it and give u feedback.. :)

Comment: Ok. try it and give a feedback. :)

Comment: yes it works for me..
and i assigned that html to web view